# How to fix file/image update problem in PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

When I'am updating image/file database doesn't save path but only temporary path that looks like `"C:\xampp\tmp\php4831.tmp"`. It's must be saved in database like`"C:\xampp\htdocs\advertisment\public\public/ad_imag..."` I use  PHP and Laravel 5.7.Here is part of code of my update method in controller.

```
 $car = Car::find($id); // finding'id' of subject

 $car->name = $request->name;
 if($file = $request->hasFile('car_photo')) {
 unlink($car->car_photo); //deletes previous file

            }
     //uploads new file
     $request->file('car_photo')->move(public_path('public/ad_images'), 
     $request->file('car_photo')->getClientOriginalName());

     try {   
Car::find($id)->update($request->all());

           dd($car);


 return response()->json(
     Json::construct 
        'Resource updated succesfully',                  
              201,
              ['car' => $data]
             ),
             201
          );
          ......
          ...
```

**The  problem is** record in database which is like: `C:\xampp\tmp\php4831.tmp`,
 but it needs to be like: `C:\xampp\htdocs\advertisment\public\public/ad_images`.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Try to use `Storage` class to slove your problem. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem

Comment: That doesn't help me